# Removing PrettyPrint with XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

For some reason my below code gives the exception: `javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet`

```
public String removePrettyPrint(String xml) throws TransformerException, TransformerFactoryConfigurationError {
    String result = "";
    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    String source = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">    <xsl:output indent=\"no\" />    <xsl:template match=\"@*|node()\">        <xsl:copy>            <xsl:apply-templates select=\"@*|node()\"/>        </xsl:copy>    </xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";
    Source xslt = new StreamSource(source);
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
    Source text = new StreamSource(xml);
    transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(result));
    return result;
}
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "Removing PrettyPrint"?  Is your objective to remove the XML's indentation and newlines?  The XSLT you're currently trying to use would be expected to just reproduce the XML exactly as it is.

Comment: @Threat, to remove prentyprint you should use normalize-space() stripspace functionalities..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you pass a string as a parameter to the [StreamSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource.html), it expects it to be a URL of an XML document, not the actual XML string itself.

You probably need to use a StringReader reader here:

```
String source = "...XSL Here...";
StringReader xsltReader = new StringReader(source);
Source xslt = new StreamSource(xsltReader);
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
```

You'll probably have to do the same for the XML, assuming you are passing in XML, and not the URL to an XML document.

```
StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xml);
Source text = new StreamSource(xmlReader);
```

And for the transform itself, you may need to make use of a StringWriter

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(writer));
result = writer.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was because of encoding.. When you read a file using File() class it does encoding internally .. But when you try to load XML as string .. then you have to do it manually ..

observe the usage of `.getBytes() and ByteArrayInputStream(bytes).`

```
    String source = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">    <xsl:output indent=\"no\" />    <xsl:template match=\"@*|node()\">        <xsl:copy>            <xsl:apply-templates select=\"@*|node()\"/>        </xsl:copy>    </xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";
    byte[] bytes = source .getBytes("UTF-16");
    Source xslsource = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslsource);
```

The alternative solution would be to use StringReader:

```
    String source = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><xsl:stylesheet version=\"1.0\" xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">    <xsl:output indent=\"no\" />    <xsl:template match=\"@*|node()\">        <xsl:copy>            <xsl:apply-templates select=\"@*|node()\"/>        </xsl:copy>    </xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>";
    StringReader xslReader = new StringReader(source);
    Source xslsource= new StreamSource(xslReader);
```

which takes care of encoding automatically..

Comment: It's not an encoding problem.  As Tim C's answer explains, the `StreamSource()` constructor that takes a string parameter expects a URL, and the same goes for StreamResult().

Comment: @JLRishe, IT is encoding problem! StringReader takes care of it internally .. try the first code as well.. it doesn't pop up any compilation error!

Comment: If you change this line: `byte[] bytes = source.getBytes("UTF-16");` to `byte[] bytes = source .getBytes();`, it will work just fine.  As I said, the _reason_ the asker was getting an error was because the `StreamSource()` constructor was treating `<?xml version....` as a URL, not because of encoding.